# Binding to x:Name in XAML breaks my app in Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

This line works in Windows Phone 7.0 but not in 7.1 (`NullReferenceException` thrown). Note that I checked that Name is never null or empty.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="{Binding Name}" Content="{Binding Label}" />
```

Removing `x:Name`, all things being equal, prevent the app to crash. Why is that ?

Comment: Where are you setting the datacontext?

Comment: In my constructor : `DataContext = App.AdsViewModel;`. Since not putting `x:Name` (but still having bindings in `Content`) works, I don't think the `DataContext` is not set. Also, I logged my view model data in the constructor, and I have to appropriate `Name` and `Label`

Comment: Try declaring it in the XAML. Do you have a ViewModelLocator?

Comment: What do you mean, declaring it in the XAML ? App.AdsViewModel is created and populated at runtime. In my XAML I have a DataContext populated with DesignData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind `x:Name` , it's the equivalent of declaring a variable in C#. And it doesn't make sense to do either, as it's not a visual property.

Surely you meant to bind the `Header` property of the CheckBox?

Comment: You're right, I don't remember why I had that, and since I didn't used it, I deleted it, but I didn't cause any problem in 7.0. I'll change my accepted answer if anyone can explain

Comment: It *should* cause problem in 7.0 as well. It's *never* been valid to bind the x:Name property. For obvious reasons, as the name is used as variable name in the generated BAML.

Answer (score 0):

My openion is Name property didn't take at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded from 7.0 to 7.1 the xmlns:x in your header might be wrong. create a brand new page and make sure that that line is the same.

Comment: A brand new page has the same values :     `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`
`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
Moreover, if I set a static value, like `x:Name="test"` it works